# Right way to install kubectl for a 1.25 cluster in GKE?

Tags: kubernetes, google-cloud-platform, google-kubernetes-engine, kubectl

I have created a cluster in GKE, running the **1.25** version of Kubernetes.

I need to setup kubectl locally on Ubuntu Server.

I am aware that I must use a kubectl version that is within one minor version difference to the cluster.

I have currently installed the Google Cloud CLI.  From here it appears I can either install kubectl as an add-on to the CLI or a separate install.

**What is the best way to install kubectl on my local machine to work against a 1.25 cluster in GKE?**

Comment: I'd start  by installing kubectl and the gcp aith plugin following https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/how-to/cluster-access-for-kubectl.

If you end up with any incompatibility issues, you can always manually install and link to an earlier version of kubectl

Comment: Kubernetes Skew policy allows you to use components that are 2 versions ahead or behind each other. So for a kubernetes cluster version 1.25 you can use kubectl 1.23, 1.24, 1.26 or 1.27. Just use gcloud and install kubectl as Gari mentioned